# Image Carousel in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I need to create image viewer and it should show 3-4 previews of images like image carousel. Here it is an example

[image: http://cdn.tripwiremagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/iQuery_thumb.jpg]

How can I create such effect in android .If someone has code example , I would be very grateful if you share it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out my answer it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [3D carousel](http://code.google.com/p/android-3d-carousel-view/) controll in android.

A Data controls take various forms, one of the mostly used being the Listview. With the emerging "finger friendly" technologies, various controls have been developed to take advantage of easier data browsing. Android's natively supports the Gallery view which is implemented from the [Coverflow Control](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html)

Hope this will guide you.

Comment: seems to be absolutely helpful to him